# parsing json from multiple url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

I want to parse json data from multiple url. I tried using for loop but it only parse json data from 1 url, while i want to show data from all urls.

I have a working script, but it is hardcoding. This is part of my script.

```
const apiex1 = 'http://www.ex.com/example1.json';
const apiex2 = 'http://www.ex.com/example2.json';

$.getJSON(apiex1, ex1Weather);
$.getJSON(apiex2, ex2Weather);

function ex1Weather(report) {
    weatherData(report);
    document.querySelector('tbody.ex1').innerHTML = apiWeather;
}
function ex2Weather(report) {
    weatherData(report);
    document.querySelector('tbody.ex2').innerHTML = apiWeather;
}
```

I have around 30 data/urls, using this script just overwhelming since the data will increase. What is the best way to make a better configuration for this script?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use a loop over an array of URLs instead of hardcoding each one.

```
const apiUrls = ['http://ex.com/example1.json', 'http://ex.com/example2.json'];
apiUrls.forEach((url, index) => {
    $.getJson(url, report => {
        weatherData(report);
        document.querySelector('tbody.ex' + index).innerHTML = apiWeather;
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this code but the $.getJSON not working, I try to log something but doesn't return anything. I tried this in jsfiddle but it return error '$.getJson is not a function'

Comment: You're the one using `$.getJson`. It's from jQuery, so if you're going to run it in jsfiddle, you need to include the jQuery library.

Comment: Oh you can test this code. I know that it should work, but for some reason, it is not.

Comment: Well, just forget about this problem. I'll rebuild my code architecture anyway.